# Sitecore lost of br tags added to FullDescription and Description fields

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

I am using sitecore 9

I have an Description field (contains 3 words inside a `<p>This is a test</p>` in sitecore and a long description (which contains a html table)

the cshtml is as follows code

```
@Model.Description.Render()
@Model.FullDescription.Render()
```

When i load the page the div contains a ton of `<br>` tags which were not entered in the sitecore fields

What renders is a `<div>` which contains the Description inside the `<p>` tag, then a bunch of `<br>` tags and then the Fulldescription (table)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the field type